# Initializing Apache Beam Test Pipeline in Scala fails

Tags: java, scala, pipeline, apache-beam

When I try to run a test pipeline it raise an error

here is the source code to create the test pipeline:

```
val p: TestPipeline = TestPipeline.create()
```

and here is the error :

> java.lang.IllegalStateException: Is your TestPipeline declaration missing a @Rule annotation? Usage: @Rule public final transient TestPipeline pipeline = TestPipeline.create();

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I have solve the problem by following code :

```
val p: TestPipeline = TestPipeline.create().enableAbandonedNodeEnforcement(false)
```

Comment: I am not sure how `enableAbandonedNodeEnforcement` solves the problem but note that `TestPipeline implements org.junit.rules.TestRule` (https://beam.apache.org/releases/javadoc/2.11.0/org/apache/beam/sdk/testing/TestPipeline.html#create--) and therefore should be used as a `Rule`